# Porque no entra al while con los datos que le estoy enviando?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en sql server, el la clausula WHERE hay tres opciones por NoEmployee, EPPemployee y entre dos fechas, ejecuto el estore procedure en sql y si me trae los datos de cualquiera de las tres formas:

Store procedure:

```html
PROCEDURE [dbo].[getreport]
    
    @fechareg as datetime = NULL,
    @fechafina as datetime = NULL,
    @Noemployee as int = null,
    @EPPeployee nvarchar(80) = null
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * from mitabla 
    where 
    (@Noemployee IS NULL OR NoEmpleado = @Noemployee)
    AND
    (@EPPeployee IS NULL OR EPP = @EPPeployee)
    AND
    (@fechareg IS NULL AND @fechafina IS NULL OR FechaReg BETWEEN @fechareg AND @fechafina)
```

ejecuto desde MSSQL y con pasarle cualquier de los tres datos funciona correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cuando mando los datos desde C# no me carga los datos y tampoco me marca error, es como si no encontrara nada, este es como los estoy enviando desde c# no entra al while a menos que lleve los tres datos que pide pero si solo quiero buscar por numero de empleado no entra al wile:

```html
cnnEPP.Open();
            try
            {
                comm = new SqlCommand("dbo.getreport", cnnEPP);
                comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.Clear();
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fechareg", fch1.ToShortDateString()) ;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("fechafina",fch2.ToShortDateString());
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Noemployee",nempleado);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("EPPeployee",eppEmp);
                reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        //No entra al while si solo lleva un dato para hacer la busqueda pero si pongo los 4 datos si entra al while 
               while(reader.Read())
                {
                    int row = dataGridReports.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["ColFecha"].Value = reader.GetDateTime(1).ToShortDateString();
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["ColNEmployee"].Value = reader.GetInt32(3);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["Colname"].Value = reader.GetString(2);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["ColRazon"].Value = reader.GetString(4);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["ColEpp"].Value = reader.GetString(8);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["Colcant"].Value = reader.GetInt32(5);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["Colturno"].Value = reader.GetInt32(6);
                    dataGridReports.Rows[row].Cells["ColfchCambio"].Value = reader.GetDateTime(1).ToShortDateString();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"EPP",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                cnnEPP.Close();
            }
```

Comment: no te entiendo.. estas mandando siempre 4 parametros...

Comment: No siempre y ahi es donde no entra al while cuando solo envio un parametro con datos los demas van vacios, por ejemplo si solo envio este parametro con datos comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Noemployee",nempleado) no entra al while, solo entra si todos los parametros llevan datos.

Comment: y los otros parametros, como haces para no enviarlos???

Answer (score 0):

creo que debes validar si el parameto va vacio, si es ai entonces mandarle (object)DBNull.Value para que tu condicion (@parametro IS NULL OR campo = @parametro) se invalide y pase a la siguiente, y así con todos los parametros, algo así:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", requisicion.Id > 0 ? requisicion.Id : (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).